# What font awesome fa-icon-code css class should I use for forum link in sticky footer in website?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

For the link to `Help` section of the webpage, I am using `<i class="fa fa-lg fa-question-circle"></i>` for icon in the sticky footer of the webpage.

What fa-class should i use for the link to `Forum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we use these icons,

- [commenting](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/commenting/)
- [commenting-o](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/commenting-o/)
- [comments](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comments/)
- [comments-o](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comments-o/)

You can also build a custom icon by using set of icons available in the font-awesome icon set by stacking and aligning them accordingly.[Stacked Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked)

Here I designed something for you.You can use this as a forum icon.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
   <i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-stack-1x" style="margin-left:12px;"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack"></i>
</span>
```