# Have Two Font Awesome Icons in One i Tag

Tags: font-awesome

I've been scouring the web, and I can't find an answer to this.  Is there away to add two Font Awesome icons in one i tag?

I can do it if I put two i tags side by side, like this:

```
Good for: <i class="fa fa-male fa-2x"></i><i class=" fa fa-female fa-2x"></i>
```

So is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Not as far as I know but what you can do if you wanna lay one over another (so if that's your intention) you can simply do that with CSS.

Comment: Not one over the other, just have two different icons side by side.  In one i tag.

Comment: is it ok to have one `i` tag and with in it 2 `span` tags? :)

Comment: Before investing too much effort into icon fonts one should consider that the current trend in web design moves _away_ from icon fonts. Two main reasons: limited in how they can be styled and poison for barrier reduction attempts.

Comment: @arkascha What are people moving trending towards then?

Comment: Ah, sorry! SVGs are getting more and more used as a replacement: http://ianfeather.co.uk/ten-reasons-we-switched-from-an-icon-font-to-svg/ or more general https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glyph-based fonts like this generally function by changing the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) of the element to a specific value, which the font picks up and renders as the appropriate glyph.

So it's unlikely that you'll be able to use a single tag to display both of them unless the library provides specific syntax for handling that behavior on it's own (similar to how Font Awesome uses [stacking](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked)).

Comment: OK, thank you.  Is there a more efficient way of adding two font awesome icons beside having two i tags side by side?

Comment: IMO, the two tags approach is probably going to be the easiest and cleanest.

Comment: OK.  Thanks a lot!  I'll choose your answer as the best answer when I'm able to.  Stupid timer.

Comment: Isn't _every_ font amongst the "Glyph-based fonts"? ;-)

Comment: @arkascha Yup :) I probably should think of a better term to use as people don't really think of letters as them

Answer (score 3):

With **Font Awesome 5**, it's possible!

> Masking
>
> Combine two icons create one single-color shape, thanks to the power of SVG in Font Awesome 5! Use it with our new Power Transforms for some really awesome effects.

Go through the Masking section in [this link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js).

The below snippet is a small working example taken from their site

```html
<!-- Important : Use the SVG & JS method and reference the Js file, not the CSS file -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="fa-4x">
  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" data-fa-transform="shrink-10 up-.5" data-fa-mask="fas fa-comment" style="background:MistyRose"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" data-fa-transform="shrink-3.5 down-1.6 right-1.25" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle" style="background:MistyRose"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-headphones" data-fa-transform="shrink-6" data-fa-mask="fas fa-square" style="background:MistyRose"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in a single `<i>` tag, reason is the way *how* the glyph identifying classes are applied. For longer or dynamic sequences you *can* however directly use the icons codes in markup notation:

- html: `<span class="font-awesome">&#xf183&#xf182</span>`
- css: `.font-awesome { font-family: FontAwesome; }`

This obviously requires that you load the font as `FontAwesome`.

I created a fiddler as simple demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/6ofmn36g/

I do agree though that this is an approach that is somewhat hard to read, though...

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed the notation and added a fiddler as a demonstration.

Comment: Nice!! this would have been the exact same solution I would have given too.. +1

Comment: Great solution. For rapid icons reference see https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/variables.less

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with current library of FontAwesome. But there are work arounds as **arkascha** has suggested below.

---

---

Additional Info:

**Not exactly what you are asking for** But I think this will help you, Also future crowd who falls into this thread with the title.

I had answered similar stuff... Here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491858/2592042

You can also build a custom icon by using set of icons available in the font-awesome icon set by stacking and aligning them accordingly. [Stacked Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked)

Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
   <i class="fa fa-male fa-stack-1x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-female fa-stack"></i>
</span>
```